# set uiview from other uiviewcontrolelr

Tags: uiview

I try to set an uiview from the app delegate to an other viewcontroller, in viewcontroller I add an IBOutlet property and from app delegate I use this code:

```
self.secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

self.secondViewController.myView = view;

self.window.rootViewController = self.secondViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

but the view of my uiviewcontroller isn't red, but the default color that I give from IB.

where is the error?

Comment: How about `self.secondViewController.view = view;` instead of `myView`?

Comment: Why are you setting a view up in a different view controller? This seems fishy to me.